# block re-creation of specific auxiliary files

Tags: table-of-contents, errors, auxiliary-files, workflow

From time to time I'd like to temporarily disable the creation of some *specific* auxiliary file. Actual examples have been:

- At a late state of editing a document fixing something in the `.toc`-file directly was the easiest way to obtain a certain result. (I know that this is ugly and potentially dangerous, but ...)
- Working with `reledpar` obtaining balanced layouts can require a lot of compilations, each of which can be pretty time consuming. When the result has finally settled (and has been written to auxiliary files) I don't want to break it when I change details in the texts potentially making typos that result in compilation-errors.

`\nofiles` will help in the first case but will block the creation of *all* auxiliary files. `reledpar`'s custom files are not affected by `\nofiles` at all.

Locking the files in question by the operating system works for both cases, but has the disadvantage of throwing "I can't write on file..."-errors that require me to react.

So I am looking for a way to customise `\nofiles` to only block *specific* files.

Or could an alternative be to instruct TeX just to give up on writing files that are not writable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has a hand edited LOT, leaving every other write untouched (lot writes are redirected to the log file)

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.lot}
\contentsline {table}{\numberline {1}{HERE ztztztz}}{100}
\contentsline {table}{\numberline {2}{THERE ztztztzzzz}}{200}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\tmplot{lot}
\def\@starttoc#1{%
  \begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \@input{\jobname.#1}%
    \if@filesw
      \def\tmp{#1}%
      \ifx\tmp\tmplot
        \expandafter\let\csname tf@#1\endcsname\m@ne
       \else
         \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
         \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
        \fi
    \fi
    \@nobreakfalse
  \endgroup}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\section{zzz}
z
\begin{table}
  \caption{ztztztz}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}
\caption{zfzfzfz}
\end{figure}

\section{zzz}
z
\begin{table}
  \caption{ztztztzzzz}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}
\caption{zfzfzfzzzz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```